# School Assignment Multidimensional Array Trouble

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods, call

I am currently working on an assignment for my Java programming class.  I seem to have got myself in a bit of a bind.  Any assistance in helping me realize what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Assignment

Write a program that does the following:

Put the data below into a multi-dimensional array

Prompts the user for the company they would like employee salary statistics.

Write a method that returns the average employee salary as a double. Pass the company number and employee Wages to this method.

Write a method that returns the total employee salary as an int. Pass the company number and employee Wages to this method.

Write a method that returns the number of employees as an int. Pass the company number and employee Wages to this method.

In the main method call the other methods and out put the results.

Keep in mind that I am still new and struggling to understand some of the principles of programming.

When I run the program I am getting locations instead of method calculations (bad output):

[image: bad output]

Here is what I have so far:

```
package salaries;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Salaries {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //declare, instantiate, and define value of multi array [3] [12]
        double [][] mSalary = { { 49920, 50831, 39430, 54697, 41751, 36110, 
                              41928, 48460, 39714, 49271, 51713, 38903},
                            { 45519, 47373, 36824, 51229, 36966, 40332,
                              53294, 44907, 36050, 51574, 39758, 53847},
                            { 54619, 48339, 44260, 44390, 39732, 44073,
                              53308, 35459, 52448, 38364, 39990, 47373}};

        //declare, instantiate, and define value
        //of single array for company names
        //and output values to user for selection
        String [] company = { "Alhermit", "Logway", "Felter" };
        for( int i = 0; i < company.length; i++ )
            System.out.println( "Company " + i + " : " +company[i] );

        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
        int cCompany;
        do{
            //ouput for user to select a company
            System.out.print("Select company: (0)" +company[0]+ ", (1)"
                            +company[1]+ "; (2)" +company[2]+ " > ");
            //scan user input into cCompany
            cCompany = scan.nextInt();


            //call number method
            num nums = new num();
            nums.number(mSalary, cCompany);

            //call total method
            total sum = new total();
            sum.total(mSalary, cCompany);

            //call average method
            avg cAvg = new avg();
            cAvg.average(mSalary, cCompany);


            //output statistics to user on selected company
            System.out.println( "You have selected the company " + company[cCompany] + ". " );
            System.out.println( company[cCompany] + " has " + nums + " of employees." );
            System.out.println( "A total employee salary of " + sum + "." );
            System.out.println( "The average employee salary is " + cAvg );
        }
            while( cCompany < 0 || cCompany > 2);
    }
}

//total class to calculate
//salary of user selected company
class total {

    public static int total( double [][] mSalary, int cCompany ){

        //assign variables
        int sum = 0;

        //for loop to calculate salary total of user input company
        for( int j = 0; j < mSalary[cCompany].length; j++ ){
            sum += mSalary[cCompany][j];

        }

    //return statement
    return sum;
    }
}

//average class to calculate
//average of user selected company
class avg {

    public static double average( double [][] mSalary, int cCompany){

        //assign variables
        int cAvg = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        //totals the values for the selected company by
        //iterating through the array with count.
        while( count < mSalary[cCompany].length){
            sum += mSalary[cCompany][count];
            count +=1;
        }

            cAvg = sum / mSalary[cCompany].length;
            return cAvg;
    }
}
//number class to calculate amount of
//employees in user selected company
class num {

    public static int number( double [][] mSalary, int cCompany){

        //assign variables
        int nums = 0;

        //number of employees based on length of colomn
        nums = mSalary[cCompany].length;
        return nums;
    }
}
```

Comment: You link to an image of "bad output" (don't use images; include as text in your question), but you've not said what "correct output" would be; nor what stage of the assignment you are currently stuck on.

Comment: I can see is a LOT of style problems including Incorrect class names, incorrect indentation, inconsistent whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

`nums`, `sum`, and `cAvg` are all instances of classes that you have, you're printing out the instances of those classes.

(By the way - you should change the name of these classes.  Classes start with a capital letter.  It differentiates them from variables.)

There are two things wrong with this.

1. You are instantiating a class which contains *no data* and has no `toString` method.
2. You're instantiating a class which only has static methods to return the data from.  You don't need to instantiate the class at *all*; instead, just print the result of the method call.

That would change at least one of these calls to something like:

```
System.out.println( company[cCompany] + " has " + num.number(mSalary, cCompany); + " of employees." );
```

I leave the rest as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it got me exactly where I needed to be.  I removed the unnecessary code to instantiate the static methods and I replaced my output statement to reflect as you showed.  I have also corrected the issue with my class names to make them capital letters.  Everything is working great.  Your reply was quick and a tremendous help.  Thank you!!

Comment: After I got it working, I went back and removed the declarations of the three classes and placed my method code inside the main class and then changed my output statement to reflect the change.  Less code, less processing, and looks a lot cleaner.